# ANTLR4 Auto-Generated FIles full of errors

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm a complete beginner in language design and implementation, and I'm a fairly inexperienced programmer in general. I'm trying to use ANTLR4 to make my own programming language, but first I wanted to [follow a tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/) so I could get a sense of how to approach my own project. In the linked tutorial, I am trying to follow the Spreadsheet Project(Items #29-32), as I am only really comfortable with C# and that is the only tutorial project which uses it. I managed to create the grammar easily enough, and it seemingly compiles just fine when running this command:

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=CSharp Spreadsheet.g4`

This generates the required files:

[image: File System after Generation]

Here's where I run into some problems. Namely, the files generated by ANTLR seem to be full of errors:

[image]
(I'm only showing a picture here because there are too many errors to write out all of them. If any specific ones need to be specified let me know and I will write those ones out.)

The tutorial gives me the `Program` class:

```
using System;
using Antlr4.Runtime;

namespace AntlrTutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "log(10 + A1 * 35 + (5.4 - 7.4))";

            AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(input);
            SpreadsheetLexer spreadsheetLexer = new SpreadsheetLexer(inputStream);
            CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(spreadsheetLexer);
            SpreadsheetParser spreadsheetParser = new SpreadsheetParser(commonTokenStream);

            SpreadsheetParser.ExpressionContext expressionContext = spreadsheetParser.expression();
            SpreadsheetVisitor visitor = new SpreadsheetVisitor();

            Console.WriteLine(visitor.Visit(expressionContext));
        }
    }
}
```

Which brings many new errors to the party. For instance:

> Error CS1729  'SpreadsheetLexer' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

It seems that the line in question points to `Spreadsheet.g4.lexer.cs` instead of the generated `SpreadsheetLexer.cs`, which does contain the constructor. I have no idea why it is pointing where it is, if that is the intended funtionality, or how to fix it if not.

I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/issues/39) which seems to cover a similar issue, but I have no idea if my situation is the same, and I don't know how to fix it if so.

If anyone has any clue what my problem(s) might be and how I can fix them, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: It is pretty bad if a tutorial uses an arbitrary version of the Java compiler to generate C# source code. Stop following that and instead use a real world project as your example, or follow https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs